# Using jQuery to make a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I'm trying to make a simple jQuery popup on an existing page. The page itself will have the first part of some articles, with a more button following the intro. I would like the more button to display a jQuery popup with the rest of the article.

So far, I've been following the tutorial: http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

However once it's up on share point, it doesn't work. I click the button and nothing happens. I even modified the JS so all it does it display an alert, but that doesn't work ether. The link between the page and JS seems to be broken. However I even viewed the src (using my web browser) and sure enough the script tag is in there, but nothing JS is working. Any ideas?

Here's the html page I copy into share point (the java script file is exactly the same as in the tutorial):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/articles/.../popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* CSS goes here, same as in the tutorial */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="backgroundmain" style="margin-left:-75px; margin-top:-35px; margin-right:-32px;">
            <!-- HTML FOR THE ARTICLES-->
            </div>
            <center>
                <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Press me please!" /></div>
            </center>
            <div id="popupContact">
                <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
                <h1>Title of our cool popup, yay!</h1>
                <p id="contactArea">
                    Here we have a simple but interesting sample of our new stuning and smooth popup...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it.

**EDITS:**

Here's the results from Chrome's dev tools:

jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.
popup.js:147Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

However I first tried this in firebug and discovered the alert actually works in firefox.

Comment: Open this up using Firebug or Chrome dev tools (or IE dev tools if you're desperate) and look and see if there are any Javascript errors. If there are, then the rest of the Javascript will not function. Post your findings when you do.

Comment: Step one is to try to load the page and click the button in an environment where you can get complete error information.  For example, in Firefox with Firebug running, or in Chrome using the developer tools.  It's also worth using a tool (such as the Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox) that will let you view the rendered source of the page, so you can see whether Sharepoint is changing something in your source code that's breaking this.

Comment: Since you're using JQuery, alternative to using FireBug or other developer console would be using [jquery lint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks suspect:

```
<script src="/articles/.../popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where exactly is popup.js?  If you have it locally, make sure the path is correct.  If not you will need to specify the URL to the file and not a relative path.